# Http is not working even adding Exception Domain in IBM Worklight?

Tags: ios, http, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using xcode 7.3. While parsing values to http server the following log is received "App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file".
Even after adding "App transport security settings" and setting "Allow arbitrary load = Yes", the same error is received. Adding Exception domain also does the same.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>

        <key>192.9.200.38</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>192.9.200.91</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>

    </dict>
</dict>
```

How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are those IP addresses translate to...? They may be the wrong ones to use.

See the following blog post regarding IBM MobileFirst Platform and ATS: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/09/09/ats-and-bitcode-in-ios9/

Add this (and only this, replacing whatever you have now):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>localhost</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```